# I don't understand how logarithmic function is inverse function of an exponential function

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation, inverse-function

I know how to solve problems, but I don't understand the core theory that sticks these two functions with this special relation.

Could you help me find the core idea that I need to understand in order to be satisfied with my understanding?

Comment: Exponential is the function that satisfies $y'(t)=y(t)$ with $y(0)=1$. If $z(s)$ is the inverse function of $y(t)$, then $t=z(y(t))$. Taking derivatives you get that $1=z'(y(t))y'(t)=z'(y(t))y(t)$. This means that $z$ satisfies $z'(s)=\frac{1}{s}$ and $z(1)=0$. Therefore, $z(s)=\int_{1}^{s}\frac{dx}{x}$. So, $z(s)=\ln(s)$.

Comment: There are many different approaches to the logarithmic and exponential functions.  In some, you start by defining one of them and then define the other as its inverse function.  How do you prefer to define them?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Whichever approach You would prefer, Sir. I would really like to see any further Approaches to this, definitely without using some more advanced axioms and nomenclature,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of $\exp x$ are positive.  The domain of $\log x$ is the positive numbers.
If $x$ is a real number, then $\log(\exp(x)) = x$.
If $x>0$ then $\exp(\log(x)) = x$.

This is is why we say the two functions $\exp$ and $\log$ are "inverse functions".

Comment: Sure, but how can we show it using some formal function definitions, as in the composition of these two functions and some inverse function identities?

Comment: Because as much as I like this straightforward explanation I still don't get the formal ideas used to express your reasoning in more general case,

Answer (score 0):

Just an illustration.

Geometrically, in 2D, 
the curves $y=\exp(x)$ and $y=\ln(x)$
are the mirror images of each other
with respect to line $y=x$.

[image]